# Waiting for an Ajax call within forEach within function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, foreach

I am stuck with a function that has to process an array, and as part of this it has to loop over it and perform an ajax call using a value to determine if it's valid. If errors are found it returns a string of error messages after it has processed all the data. How do I ensure the ajax calls all complete before the functions returns, bearing in mind that they will only fire on some loops?

I've tried all sorts of deferred / promise related things but can't get it right :(
I don't believe this is as straightforward as "how do I get return async data" due to the forEach, or even if the principle is the same I'm struggling with the implimentation.

Trimmed code below - note the // Do other stuffs - both within the forEach in case that makes a difference. A watcher calls `handleFileSelect()`, which then calls `basicValidation()`;

```
function basicValidation( data ) {
    // Store errors to be returned.
    var failed = '';
    // Loop over each row and validate.
    data.forEach( function( row, index ) {

        // Do other stuff.

        if ( a ) {
            // Do stuff.
        } else if (b) {
            // Do ajax bit that only happen sometimes.
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/' + row[5],
                success: function (data) {
                    if ( 200 !== data.status ) {
                        failed += 'Row ' + index + ':: invalid Address - lookup failed.\n';
                    }
                    // Do other checks.
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    console.log(  'Postcode lookup request failed:: ' + request.responseText + '\n' + status + '\n' + error );
                }
            });
        }

        // Do other stuff.
    }

    return failed;
}


function handleFileSelect( results ) {
    // Do the basic front-end validation.
    var validation = basicValidation( results.data );
    if ( validation.length ) {
        alert( 'Failed.\n\n' + validation + '\nPlease correct your data, refresh the page, and try again.' );
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: look into `$.when`

Comment: your big problem is that both the functions you've shown want to return a synchronous result (`failed` and `false`) - this can not happen once you've introduced asynchronous code - so, how `handleFileSelect` is called will also need to be changed

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX - but I need a bit more handholding. I can do a basic async function using $.Deferred() and $.when, but I can't get it working in this specific context.

Comment: In handleFileSelect I can do:
`var validation = basicValidation( results.data );
$.when( validation ).done(function( results ) {
if ( results.length ) {
alert( 'Failed.\n\n' + results + '\nPlease correct your data, refresh the page, and try again.' );
return false;
}
});`
Which works for a simple async function, but it's getting the basicValidation function function setup correctly I'm having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `async: false` in your AJAX?

According to [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> async (default: true) Type: Boolean By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option to false.

This will wait for the response before continuing.

```
// Do ajax bit.
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/' + row[5],
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if ( 200 !== data.status ) {
                    failed += 'Row ' + index + ':: invalid Address - lookup failed.\n';
                }
                // Do other checks.
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                console.log(  'Postcode lookup request failed:: ' + request.responseText + '\n' + status + '\n' + error );
            }
        });
```

Comment: synchronous requests in the main thread are deprecated

Comment: It's very bad practice to use `async: false`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jeramiah-harland - but that gives me scary deprecated warnings!

Comment: Yes honestly it was not the right answer, I should've done additional work looking into it. Hopefully you were able to get your situation resolved.